# What's the best practice for holding secret files in django?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to access a secret JSON file within my module.

1. How can I locate the path of this file in Django?
2. Is holding files within the application folder considered a good practice?

```
from pathlib import Path
from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials


def report_generator():
    SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']
    KEY_FILE_LOCATION = Path('./clientSec.json')
    VIEW_ID = '123456789'
    START_DATE = '2020-10-01'
    END_DATE = 'today'

    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(KEY_FILE_LOCATION, SCOPES)

    # Build the service object.
    analytics = build('analyticsreporting', 'v4', credentials=credentials)

    # Calling API's
    response = analytics.reports().batchGet(body={
        'reportRequests': [{
            'viewId': VIEW_ID,
            'dateRanges': [{'startDate': START_DATE, 'endDate': END_DATE}],
            'metrics': [
                {"expression": "ga:pageviews"},
                {"expression": "ga:avgSessionDuration"}
            ], "dimensions": [
                {"name": "ga:deviceCategory"}
            ]
        }]}).execute()
```

This is my folder structure.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way would be to make them as environment variables when you host the application. You can also do this while in development, and you can use the os library to get them.